# Xmpp message boundary

Tags: xmpp

I am building an application which receives XMPP message from different nodes in the system and processing it. Traffic volume will be high for this application. So i have implemented worker threads to do the processing.

Thus application receives XMPP message from socket and passes it to worker thread for xml parsing of the messages received. Each thread has separate parser contexts.

To be on safer side i want to make sure that when i pass a message to worker thread it is a single complete xmpp message. Would like to get your valuable suggestion for the approach.

Answer (score 0):

It will be hard, if not impossible, to implemented the distribution of the work on that level.   XMPP stanzas have no length encoding, so you don't know where the stanza ends until you have parsed it. I also doubt that most parser will provide separate parser contexts for parsers that operate on the same stream socket.

May I suggest that you setup one worker per socket, that parses the stanzas and distributes the parsed stanzas to your worker threads?

Comment: Initially i thought to implement that way. But dropped it because xml parsing seemed to be a bulky procedure and passing the message after xml parsing to worker thread does not seem to be saving the effort which is desired. I want to keep the receiver thread only for receiving the message from socket so xml parsing in worker thread was looking optimal solution.